# Finding an Image in a iFrame, both with generated ID's

Tags: jquery

I have a page with runtime generated iFrames and Images. Both have a standard ID, but is appended with a generated number, so iframe may have a name of "banking_iframe_12345" which has an image inside of it, also with a generated id like "banking_image_45678".

I need to find out if the image exists as sometimes it's not created.

I've tried the wild card Jquery/JS search which is not able to find the image, even if I can see it in the inspector which makes me think I've done something wrong with my search

```
var img = $('iframe[id^="banking_iframe"]').contents().find($('[id*="banking_image_"]')).html();
```

No matter what, I get "undefined" for the image search, even if I can see the image display and appear in the inspector

Comment: do you have errors in console? CORS?

Comment: No, no errors, no CORS issues. Just "undefined"